# Express NodeJS and Unfulfilled Promises

Tags: node.js, express, q

When a request times out in Express (seems to be 2 minutes by default?), does it terminate any threads or operations spawned by the initial request? I'm trying to debug an issue where the request never completes (res.send/end is never called). I suspect this is because of an error in a Q promise somewhere that is never fulfilled. After the timeout event, everything in the app seems to run slowly for a while. I'm wondering if some activity from the initial request is still running.

So:

1. Would a timeout terminate any operations spawned by the initial request
2. Any ideas on how to diagnose what promise is not getting fulfilled?

UPDATE:

I'm guessing my unfulfilled promise is something along the lines of the following:

```
var deferred = q.defer();

// do something with a bunch of regular callbacks

return deferred.promise;
```

and my deferred is never getting resolved or rejected. So my promise will not throw an error. Is there a way to track such "never-fulfilled" promises?

Comment: I have a few comments. 1)I think there is a package that sets a default timeout for express requests.  2) The timeout would terminate the operations because it will be seen as an error so your promise will not get fulfilled, so your next() middleware call should not get called(unless with error) 3) if you are running the app locally you should be able to check which promise is not getting fulfilled by logging an error with the Q fail callback or the second function in the then() statement and checking your terminal

Comment: Actually, this is node; you are not dealing with threads per se. But I have a hard time understanding the context of the question. In the case of promises, you are not executing something until something else happens, but *waiting* until something happens. E.g. `doSomething().then(function(){})` the `.then()` function does **not** get called until the promise is resolved or rejected. So maybe a bit more info including some code?

Comment: Also, personally, I think Express and NodeJS fulfill their promises admirably! :-)

Comment: The "thread" will not be terminated... it isn't really a thread though, it will simply go down a path of being handled with an error response.  Usually the error handling is done as a middleware function, so you could log where the error is coming from in that middleware.